# Function pointer assignment for struct member causes type casting mismatch and eventually segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, struct, function-pointers

I wrote the following program to help me learn function pointers and their use within structures:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct S_t S_t;

struct S_t {
    float *s_ptr;
    uint32_t ns;
};

typedef struct p_t p_t;

struct p_t {
    int32_t pID;
    float pVal;
};


typedef struct pr_t pr_t;

struct pr_t {
    S_t *S;
    int (*TrimS)(S_t *TS, int sSize);
    p_t *TP;
};

int ChopS(S_t *TS, int size);


float fvals[] = {0.8000000119209290, 0.2399999946355820, -0.3740000128746033, 
                0.2489999979734421, 0.9049999713897705, 0.3770000040531158, 
                -0.6959999799728394, -0.8870000243186951, -0.9739999771118164, 
                0.1410000026226044, 0.4040000140666962, 0.7779999971389771};
int arrLen = sizeof(fvals) / sizeof(fvals[0]);
float svals[20];

int ChopS(S_t *TS, int size)
{
    int i, c;
    for(i = 0; i < TS->ns; i++)
    {
        if (i >= size)
            TS->s_ptr[i] = 0.0;
    }
    c = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < TS->ns; i++)
    {
    if(TS->s_ptr[i] == 0.0)
        c++;
    }
    if (c == size)
    return 0;
    else
    return -1;
}


int main()
{
    int i, n;
    
    p_t p1 = {.pID = 1234, .pVal = 0.35};
    p_t *p2 = NULL;
    
    S_t tS1;
    S_t *tS2 = NULL;
    tS2 = malloc(sizeof(S_t));
    
    pr_t SP1;
    pr_t *SP2 = NULL;
    SP2 = malloc(sizeof(pr_t));

    p2 = (p_t *) malloc(sizeof(p_t));
    p2->pID = 1111;
    p2->pVal = 1.198;

    printf("Generating new values from original inputs as float array : \n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        svals[i] = 1 + fvals[i];
        printf("%f, ", svals[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    tS1.s_ptr = fvals;
    tS1.ns = arrLen;

    tS2->s_ptr = svals;
    tS2->ns = arrLen;

    SP1.S = &tS1;
    SP1.TP = &p1;
    SP1.TrimS = ChopS(&tS1, 4);
    printf("Original inputs from PR1 (Trim=%d) as %d inputs : \n", 
        SP1.TrimS, SP1.S->ns);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%f, ", SP1.S->s_ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    SP2->S = tS2;
    SP2->TP = p2;
    SP2->TrimS = ChopS(&tS2, 8);
    printf("Modified inputs from PR2 (Trim=%d) as %d inputs : \n", 
        SP2->TrimS, SP2->S->ns);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%f, ", SP2->S->s_ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

It gives me the following warnings when I compile:

```
user@PCLT:~/Test$ gcc -std=c99 -Wall -o executetest exp.c
exp.c: In function ‘main’:
exp.c:95:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    SP1.TrimS = ChopS(&tS1, 4);
            ^
exp.c:96:45: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int (*)(S_t *, int) {aka int (*)(struct S_t *, int)}’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("Original inputs from PR1 (Trim=%d) as %d inputs : \n",
                                            ~^
        *(SP1.TrimS), SP1.S->ns);
        ~
exp.c:106:24: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ChopS’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    SP2->TrimS = ChopS(&tS2, 8);
                        ^
exp.c:39:5: note: expected ‘S_t * {aka struct S_t *}’ but argument is of type ‘S_t ** {aka struct S_t **}’
int ChopS(S_t *TS, int size)
    ^~~~~
exp.c:106:16: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    SP2->TrimS = ChopS(&tS2, 8);
                ^
exp.c:107:45: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int (*)(S_t *, int) {aka int (*)(struct S_t *, int)}’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("Modified inputs from PR2 (Trim=%d) as %d inputs : \n",
                                            ~^
     *(SP2->TrimS), SP2->S->ns);
     ~
```

And when I run the executable, I get the following:

```
user@PCLT:~/Test$ ./executetest
Generating new values from original inputs as float array :
1.800000, 1.240000, 0.626000, 1.249000, 1.905000, 1.377000, 0.304000, 0.113000, 0.026000, 1.141000, 1.404000, 1.778000,
Original inputs from PR1 (Trim=-1) as 12 inputs :
0.800000, 0.240000, -0.374000, 0.249000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I got the desired result when I used the non-pointer `pr_t` variable SP1 but didn't get the result I needed when I used the pointer `pr_t` variable SP2. I am unable to find what went wrong as I tried to the best of my abilities. Can someone help me point out what I'm doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

I modified the above code (on suggestions given by @pm100 and @dmedine in the comments below) by replacing line 95 in the above code with:

```
SP1.TrimS = ChopS;
SP1.TrimS(&tS1, 4);
```

and line 106 with:

```
SP2->TrimS = ChopS;
SP2->TrimS(tS2, 8);
```

and it runs fine. But now, the problem is with lines 96 and 107 which prints in the form `(Trim=94135985899402)` while I was expecting something along the lines `(Trim=0)` (here, I am trying to make sure that the input array "trim" status is set to 0, meaning the operation was a success). What could be possibly wrong here?

Comment: `SP1.TrimS = ChopS(&tS1, 4);` should be `SP1.TrimS = ChopS`, you then need to call it

Comment: Those warnings aren't just wishful thinking on the compilers part. It is trying to tell you you're doing something *wrong*. In this case, several 'somethings'.

Comment: pm100 is exactly right. You are not using the correct syntax for function pointers. Assign first `SP1.TrimS = ChopS` then call `SP1.TrimS(&tS1, 4)`. The way you've written it is that you assign the return value of `ChopS` (which is an `int`) to the pointer `SP1.TrimS`. The compiler warning tells you this. Also, maybe work on making variable names a bit less 1979---take advantage of modern computers' vast disk space and type words that mean something. Finally, maybe reduce your problem to an essential code example so that it isn't so sprawling. Good luck.

Comment: Great. That worked well. Also, `printf("Modified inputs from PR2 (Trim=%d) as %d inputs : \n",  SP2->TrimS, SP2->S->ns);` prints `(Trim=94775067805578)` while I was expecting `(Trim=0)`. I tried typecasting yet I get the same error. Can you tell me what's going wrong here as well?