# How to access the value of a struct member which stores return value of a function pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, function-pointers

I have the following structure definitions:

```
typedef struct S_t S_t;

struct S_t {
    float *s_ptr;
    uint32_t ns;
};

typedef struct p_t p_t;

struct p_t {
    int32_t pID;
    float pVal;
};


typedef struct pr_t pr_t;

struct pr_t {
    S_t *S;
    int (*TrimS)(S_t *TS, int sSize);
    p_t *TP;
};
```

I also have the following function defined:

```
int success = 0;
int failure = -1;

int ChopS(S_t *TS, int size)
{
    int i, c;
    for(i = 0; i < TS->ns; i++)
    {
        if (i >= size)
            TS->s_ptr[i] = 0.0;
    }
    c = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < TS->ns; i++)
    {
    if(TS->s_ptr[i] == 0.0)
        c++;
    }
    if (c == size)
    return success;
    else
    return failure;
}
```

I do the following (full code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72779374/function-pointer-assignment-for-struct-member-causes-type-casting-mismatch-and-e)) to assign values to each member of type `pr_t` , one of whose member is `TrimS` which is a status flag function pointer:

```
    p_t *p2 = NULL;
    S_t *tS2 = NULL;
    tS2 = malloc(sizeof(S_t));
    
    pr_t *SP2 = NULL;
    SP2 = malloc(sizeof(pr_t));

    p2 = (p_t *) malloc(sizeof(p_t));

    SP2->S = tS2;
    SP2->TP = p2;
    SP2->TrimS = ChopS;
    SP2->TrimS(tS2, 8);
```

If I try to access the value of the flag using `SP2->TrimS`, I get a junk value (or an address value I think) but not `0` or `-1` as I expect. What is exactly happening over here? How can I access the value set by `ChopS` in `SP2->TrimS`?

Comment: You have to *call* the function and use the return value. The `SP2->TrimS(tS2, 8);` ignores the return value.

Comment: So, do I have to do something like this : `SP2->TrimS = SP2->TrimS(tS2, 8);` to store the return value?

Comment: @skrowten_hermit Yes, you have to. You are discarding the return value of `TrimS`. You shouldn't.

Comment: So, do I have to do something like this : `SP2->TrimS = SP2->TrimS(tS2, 8);` to store the return value? Or if `TrimS` is not like any other variable which stores a value but is only used for storing a reference to a function?

Comment: `SP2->TrimS = SP2->TrimS(tS2, 8)`  will definitely not do what you think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the function to get the return value. It is not stored anywhere and the function pointer does not store the last return value. Use it as any "normal" function

```
if(SP2->TrimS(tS2, 8) == failure)
{
    /* do something */
}
else
{
    /* do something else */
}
```

or if you want to access it later (after the call) you need to store it in the variable or have an additional struct member to store it:

```
struct pr_t {
    S_t *S;
    int (*TrimS)(S_t *, int);
    int last_TrimS_Return_Value;
    p_t *TP;
};

/* .... */

SP2 -> last_TrimS_Return_Value = SP2->TrimS(tS2, 8);
```

Comment: Ah! That makes a lot of sense now. Adding a new member is the best solution I think. New to function pointers and your explanation, especially the statement ***"Use it as any "normal" function"*** made the difference in better understanding.